# adding score when clicking inside rectangle

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following exercise to do for school:

Create a textfield which shows a score as follows "Score: " (You can use the text(StringValue, IntegerXposition, IntegerYposition) for the drawing of text), starting at zero.
Make it so that when the user clicks the left mouseButton a score of 10 is added to the result.

Create a rectangle on screen and make it so that when the user clicks inside the rectangle, a score of 20 is added to the score value.

I have done the first part but don't know how to add a score of 20 when clicking inside the rectangle. This is the code i have so far.

```
def setup():
    global Score, xPos, yPos
    size(800,800)
    textSize(30)
    Score= 0
    xPos= 200
    yPos= 200

def draw():
    global Score, xPos, yPos
    background(51)
    rect(xPos,yPos,100,100)
    text("Score: ", 50, 50)
    text(Score, 150, 50)    


def mousePressed():
    global Score, xPos, yPos
    if (mouseButton == LEFT):
        Score= Score + 10
```

Comment: Well just find out where the mouse is clicking and check if it's where you drew the rectangle. You have basically the rest of the code done for increasing the score...Give it a try and edited your question when you run into problems, that may have not been asked before.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quiet sure if this is possible with just `Python/Python 3.5.1` alone. I think `tkinter` is more suitable with making shapes with Python (And I'm not quiet sure because, I never used it before). I would suggest you use a `class` initialization for this. Here is what I got:

```
class shapesYo:
    def __init__(self, xPos, yPos):
        self.xPos = xPos
        self.yPos = yPos
        self.size = (800, 800)
    def displayPos(self):
        print("The x Position is {0} and the y Position is {1}.".format(self.xPos, self.yPos))
    def displayScore(self):
        self.Score = 0
        print("Score: {0}".format(self.Score))

rect = shapesYo(100, 100)
text = shapesYo(50, 50)
rect.displayPos()
text.displayPos()
text.displayScore()
```

This may not help out with the actual events happening (or that you want to happen) in the code but, it is a better was (in my opinion) to setup a set of code like this.

Answer (score 0):

Just check the position of the mouse pointer when there is a click.

I don't know what library you are using, but just replace `mouseX` and `mouseY` with the actual variable names.

```
def mousePressed():
    global Score, xPos, yPos
    if mouseButton == LEFT and xPos < mouseX < xPos+100 and yPos < mouseY < yPos+100:
        Score= Score + 10
```